How to execute a command for all files in a directory using the file names as arguments for the command?
I am trying to decrypt every file from an input directory to an output directory renaming the files truncating the .gpg extension in the process. (yes I am just now picking up Powershell, so if anyone throws in a link to some tutorial how to structure scripts using anything more than one commandlet I'd thankful for that already -- have the MS documentation about the commandlets, but don't know how to pass arguments, do loops, branching, ...)
$in = .\img.gpg\
$out = .\img\

# gpg -d -o filename filename.gpg
Get-ChildItem -Path $in | ForEach-Object { gpg -d -o Join-Path -Path $out -ChildPath $_.name.Substring(0,$_.name.Length-4) $_.name }


I suspected (still do) that there is some documentation about how to do flow control and pass along arguments, but did not find any. Running just
Get-ChildItem | ForEach-Object {gpg -d -o $_.name.Substring(0,$_.name.Length-4)}

in the source folder works.

you need to wrap the Join-Path expression in parentheses so its evaluated first, also the .Substring is not needed because these objects already provide the .BaseName property (Name without extension): -o (Join-Path -Path $out -ChildPath $_.BaseName)

with thanks @SantiagoSquarzon
Get-ChildItem -Path .\img.gpg\ | ForEach-Object { gpg -d -o (".\img\"+$_.BaseName) (-join(".\img.gpg\",$_.name)) }


It would probably be a good idea to use Get-ChildItem -Path $in -File -Filter '*.gpg'. Also, instead of $_.name.Substring(0,$_.name.Length-4), $_.BaseName could be used.
